# How does .NET Math.Rounding with MidpointRouding.ToEven work?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have searched for how the MidpointRouding.ToEven work. It seems it's the default rounding approach in .NET. Please check if I got it right:

1. **Math.Round(a, b)** is the same as **Math.Round(a, b, MidpointRounding.ToEven)**
2. **Math.Round(1.5) = 2** and **Math.Round(2.5)=2**
3. **Math.Round(1.15, 1) = 1.2** and **Math.Round(1.25)=2**
4. **Math.Round(1.12305, 4) = 1.1230**, just the same as **Math.Round(1.12305, 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven)**

However, I got **1.1231** instead of **1.1230** for the 4th statement (using C#). I think I must get it wrong. Somebody help explain why this would happen? 
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `double` when you care about decimal digits. I don't understand why the `Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)` overload even exists. I can't think of a single situation where using it is appropriate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `1.5` will be rounded to `2` since `2` is the nearest even number. Same logic applies to the examples 3 and 4. The OP made two mistakes 1) using `double`, not `decimal` and 2) `Math.Round(1.25m) = 1.2m` to `2` (probably just a typo).

Comment: @CodesInChaos You're right. It should just throw an exception for double so ppl don't have to scratch their hair off without a clue about what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

`1.12305` isn't exactly representable as a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx). The nearest `double` is slightly higher that `1.12305`.

If you try:

```
Math.Round(1.12305m, 4) = 1.1230
```

it'll round to `1.1230` since [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)s can exactly represent `1.12305`.

See also: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks! Damien_The_Unbeliever
You are right. Once I cast the value to decimal, it works as what I expected!